# How to add a new element to a table from a pop up window using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on this simple customers table information such as: name, lastname and age. I created a function that allows users to add a new customer and that works just fine :). I also created a pop up window and I want to add the new customer from the pop up window. My pop up window works fine, but I cannot add a new customer from it. Please help me. Thank you so much!!.

Here's my code that runs just fine

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var App = angular.module('sortApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])

App.controller('mainController', function($scope, $modal, $log, $filter) {
$scope.sortType     = 'id'; // set the default sort type
$scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order
$scope.searchPerson  = '';     // set the default search/filter term

// Array - List of People   
$scope.People = [
{ id: 1, name: 'Mike', Lastname: 'White', age: 26 },
{ id: 2, name: 'Carl', Lastname: 'Barns', age: 41 },
{ id: 3, name: 'Deb', Lastname: 'McDonals',age: 78 },
{ id: 4, name: 'Tommy', Lastname: 'Humbs', age: 32 }
];  

/*
This function adds a new customer
*/
$scope.addPerson = function(){
 var customer = {
     name: $scope.name,
     Lastname: $scope.Lastname,
     age: $scope.age,
 };

 $scope.People.push(customer);
 };
/*
This function removes a customer
*/
$scope.removePerson = function(index){
 $scope.People.splice(index, 1);
};  
 $scope.openPopupScreen = function() {

 var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  template: '<div class="modal-header">   <a class="close" data- dismiss="modal" ng-click="cancel()">X</a><h1>Add Customer</h1></div><div class="modal-body">    <form >' +
    '  <label>Name:</label><input type="text" class="span3" ng-model="name"></br>' +
    ' <label>Lastname:</label><input type="text" class="span3" ng-model="Lastname"></br>' +
    ' <label>Age:</label><input type="number" class="span3" ng-model="age"></br>' +
    ' <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addPerson()">Add In List</button>' +
    '  <button type="reset" class="btn ">Clear</button>' +
    ' </form>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="modal-footer">' +
    '  <a data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="cancel()">close</a>' +
    '</div>',
  controller: ModalInstanceCtrl
});

};

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function($scope, $modalInstance) {
$scope.ok = function() {
$modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
};

$scope.cancel = function() {
 $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
};

});
</script>
```

Comment: your code is so long to take a look, you should just include the important parts. but i see that your submit button of your modal is wrong, change it and try again     `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addPerson()">` to  `<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addPerson()">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your modal, you call addPerson() but that function is in mainController, not in modal controller so it's not working

You need to provide a function to get result in modal and pass it back to main controller, .e.g. in ModalInstanceCtrl:

```
$scope.newPerson = {
   //Bind ng-model from modal input to properties of this
};

$scope.add = function() {
    //Pass newPerson to caller from main controller
    $modalInstance.close($scope.newPerson);
};
```

Remember to bind add() to button click:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="add()">Add In List</button>
```

In main controller:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
   //create modal
});

modalInstance.result.then(function (newPerson) {
    $scope.addPerson(newPerson);
}, function () {
    //User clicks dismiss instead of add
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, Within the form in your modal popup, you should consider changing the ng-model values for all fields to something like "newPerson.name", "newPerson.age" and so on. AFAIK when you have an ng-model attribute and there is no 'dot' in there, you are doing it wrong. So within your mainController declare an empty object `$scope.newPerson` and then when adding a newPerson, add the values like name and age to this object.